# MySQL queries within a foreach loop - performance issue?

Tags: php, mysql

The array `showcasef` holds 20 items per page. I do 3 different queries within the `foreach` loop, which is 60 queries (just for the loop, there's additional queries too).

```
<?php

foreach($showcasef as $itemf){

      $sf_id = $itemf['sf_id'];
      $sf_url = $itemf['sf_url'];
      $sf_title = $itemf['sf_title'];

      $sf_urltitle = post_slug($sf_title);

      // Fetch number of favs

      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(f_id) FROM favourites WHERE f_showcaseid=?");
      $stmt->bind_param("i", $sf_id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($numfFavs);
      $stmt->fetch();
      $stmt->close();

      // Fetch class

      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT avg(r_class) FROM ranks WHERE r_showcaseid=?");
      $stmt->bind_param("i", $sf_id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($sf_class);
      $stmt->fetch();
      $stmt->close();

    // Fetch number of classes

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(r_class) FROM ranks WHERE r_showcaseid=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $sf_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($numfClasses);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
?>
```

**Render HTML here**

```
<?php } ?>
```

Will this be a severe performance issue, or are these particular queries relatively simple? If I keep the columns indexed, should it perform okay with millions of rows (potentially)? Or can the queries be optimized/simplified?

---

Here's how I get the `showcasef`:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT s_id,s_url,s_title FROM showcase WHERE s_userid=? ORDER BY s_date DESC LIMIT $skippingFactor, 20");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $u_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($sf_id,$sf_url,$sf_title);

while($stmt->fetch())
{
     $showcasef[] = [
         'sf_id' => $sf_id,
         'sf_url' => $sf_url,
         'sf_title' => $sf_title
     ];
}

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Looks very inefficient

Comment: well - it looks like you could combine those queries into one which would have considerably less of an impact on the server. In fact, you could possibly have just one sql if you prepared the `ids` ahead of the sql and used something like `where r_showcaseid in (id1,id2,id3...)` etc and then process that recordset

Comment: I added some context of how I get `showcasef`

Answer (score 3):

A few suggestions here.

**Reuse prepared statements**

You are creating three prepared statements inside the loop. Why don't you create your statements only once, and then reuse them using multiple binds?

```
<?php

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(f_id) FROM favourites WHERE f_showcaseid=?");
$stmt1->bind_param("i", $sf_id);
$stmt1->bind_result($numfFavs);
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT avg(r_class) FROM ranks WHERE r_showcaseid=?");
$stmt2->bind_param("i", $sf_id);
$stmt2->bind_result($sf_class);
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(r_class) FROM ranks WHERE r_showcaseid=?");
$stmt3->bind_param("i", $sf_id);
$stmt3->bind_result($numfClasses);

foreach($showcasef as $itemf) {
  $sf_id = ...

  $stmt1->execute();
  $stmt1->fetch();
  /* if the fetch succeedes then $numfFavs will contain the count */

  $stmt2->execute();
  ...

  $stmt3->execute();
  ..
}

$stmt1->close();
$stmt2->close();
$stmt3->close();
```

**Use a single query to Count the rows and calculate the average**

You can combine the second and third statement a single SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(r_class) AS cnt, AVG(r_class) AS average
FROM   ranks
WHERE  r_showcaseid=?
```

**Use a single query instead a foreach loop**

With the previous suggestions you can get better performances. But are you really sure you need a foreach loop?

If your IDs are returned by another query, instead of a foreach loop is better to use a subquery:

```
SELECT f_showcaseid, COUNT(f_id)
FROM favourites
WHERE f_showcaseid IN (SELECT id FROM ... WHERE ...)
GROUP BY f_showcaseid
```

or you can provide a list of IDs to the query:

```
SELECT f_showcaseid, COUNT(f_id)
FROM favourites
WHERE f_showcaseid IN (?,?,?,?,?)
GROUP BY f_showcaseid
```

(you can dynamically create the list of ? if the number of IDs is not fixed)

Comment: Regards for fast and complete answer. (I was still typing myself, but I have nothing to add.)

Comment: I tried to put the first statement out of the loop along with the `$stmt->close()` at the bottom out of it and it seemed to break the whole thing

Comment: I put both out ($stmt1 and $stmt2) and bound two variables to $stmt2 - $stmt1 seems to work but $stmt2 returns NULL on both bound variables

Comment: @frosty I updated my answer, because also the `bind_param` has to be put outside the loop. Can you pls try it? But if possible I would suggest you to use a single query with a subquery

Comment: I added `$stmt2->store_result()` and it fixed it - yes, I will try that next. Just going through the processes

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a single query I think.

Something like the following:-

```
SELECT f_showcaseid, COUNT(f_id), avg(r_class), COUNT(r_class)
FROM ranks WHERE r_showcaseid IN (".implode(',', $showcasef).")
GROUP BY f_showcaseid
```

Of course, to use parameters you would need to do that a bit more elegantly:-

```
<?php

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT f_showcaseid, COUNT(f_id), avg(r_class), COUNT(r_class)
    FROM ranks WHERE r_showcaseid IN (".implode(',', str_split(str_repeat('?', count($showcasef)), 1)).")
    GROUP BY f_showcaseid");

    foreach($showcasef as $itemf)
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $itemf['sf_id']);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($numfClasses);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

?>
```